# Share a folder with photos with someone via Internet and Apple native tools

Tags: icloud, photos, file-sharing

I have a folder of photos imported from a CD and those photos belongs to someone else. I want to share those photos with the person.

First idea was to share them through iCloud Drive but sharing is available for files and not folders.

Second idea was to use iCloud Photos shared album but the images will be added to my camera roll which I don't want too.

Is there any other Apple native solutions to share a bunch of photos with someone via Internet?

Comment: How may photos are we talking about here? There may be methods usable for small number of files (which won't scale for hundreds or thousands of photos).

Comment: Zip the photos and share the zip file via iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

The less-friction solution would be to upload the compressed version of the photos. And then use iCloud file sharing.

You can try Mail Drop.

> With Mail Drop, you can send attachments up to 5 GB in size. You can
>   send these attachments right from Mail on your Mac, the Mail app on
>   your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, and from iCloud.com on your Mac or
>   PC. All files types are supported and attachments don’t count against
>   your iCloud storage. If a message, including its attachments, is
>   larger than your Internet Service Provider (ISP) limit, Mail will ask
>   you to send the attachments using Mail Drop.

<sup>Source:https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203093</sup>